# Find Linked Rows recursively in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a table which contains multiple columns with ID and ORIGID as the columns that are used to link two records.

When a new record is entered, ID and ORIGID are same. IF a record data is modified, it gets a new ID but ORIGID points to the previous record ID that was modified.

The Data looks something like:

```
ID      ORIGID
----------------
1        1
2        1
3        2
4        4
5        3
6        6
7        5
8        8
9        9
10       7
```

I am looking for an efficient query where I should be able to see all related records when I search for Record with ID as 10 (result should include 10,7,5,3,2,1). When I search with ID 5, it should,return all rows 5,3,2,1

The query that I tried is:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
select  ID, ORIGID     from    t
where   ID = 10

UNION ALL

select  child.ORIGID
    , CASE WHEN parent.ID = child.ORIGID THEN child.ID ELSE NULL END AS prev
from
    t AS child
    inner join CTE AS parent on
        (parent.ORIGID = child.ID)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

but it returns only the first and last rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ;WITH #results AS
    (
        SELECT  id, 
                ORIGID 
        FROM    table_name
        WHERE   id = 10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.id, 
                t.ORIGID 
        FROM    table_name t
                INNER JOIN #results r ON r.ORIGID = t.id AND R.ID <> t.id

    )
    SELECT id, ORIGID
    FROM    #results ;
```

And for both past and future records

```
    ;WITH #results AS
    (
        SELECT  id, ORIGID  FROM  table_name WHERE   id = 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.id, t.ORIGID FROM    table_name t
                INNER JOIN #results r ON r.ORIGID = t.id AND R.ID <> t.id
    ),#results2 as
    (
      select ID,ORIGID from table_name where ID = 2
      union all
      select t.ID,t.ORIGID from table_name t join #results2 r  on t.ORIGID=r.id AND R.ID <> t.id
    )
    SELECT * FROM #results
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM #results2
```

Comment: how would the query look like the requirement is to get all the relevant records (past and future) for a particular ID. for eg. when we get the request for 5, we should see 10, 7 (future), 5 and then 3,2,1

Comment: you need to make 2 block queries for past and future, then combine results, I updated the answer